# Using SQL server 2017, how to convert Float (IEEE754 Single precision 32-bit) to Binary?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, sql-server-2017, ieee-754

I am more familiar with PLC than SQL.  The PLC has a built-in function for this conversion and needs to be matched with the converted value from SQL.

The values generated by PLC is in accordance with this website:
[website to convert the conversion in title](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=050046050048048048049)

I need to know if there is a built-in function available in SQL for this, or this needs to be coded in SQL from scratch. On googling, I am able to find code/built-in function for this conversion in other languages, but not for SQL.

It would be helpful if someone can share a link to SQL code or an algorithm to code from scratch in SQL.

Comment: Just a couple of converts seems to give the answer you want, unless I am missing something? `CONVERT(varbinary(4),CONVERT(real,2.20001))`

Comment: As a side note, you're probably looking for the `float(24)` data type on SQL Server to get the same `varbinary` result as your link. The default `float` is actually `float(53)` which consumes 8 bytes (64 bits) instead of 4 bytes (32 bits).

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  Actually the process involves converting 4 data (each with a different datatype  - string, float) into binary and adding all those binary data together and then taking 2's complement for that value and converting back to decimal.  The above query returns hexa-decimal.  I can add some hex values together.  But can you let me know how to convert this back to decimal again after 2's complement?

Comment: Just convert the (`varbinary`) value to a `real`, or a `float(24)`... The opposite of what I show in my first comment.

Comment: @Reshikeshstar  *Actually the process involves converting 4 data (each with a different datatype - string, float) into binary and adding all those binary data together and then taking 2's complement for that value and converting back to decimal.*  --  Why are you doing all these steps?  What is it you are actually trying to achieve here, as there is likely a more straightforward solution that renders this rather roundabout route unnecessary.

Comment: we are trying to validate integrity of the data sent from a C# application to PLC.  The app will calculate checksum of sent data and send this in a separate OPC address tag.  After receiving data, PLC will calculate checksum for the same data and will validate if the calculated value is same as the one calculated by the application.  This is necessary due to datatype definition different between sql and PLC.  Thank you